# Clear FTA (Failure to Appear in Court) from my record

Tags: california, traffic

Went to the DMV to renew my driving license and I found it was canceled due to a Failure to Appear in court and Failure to Pay a fine that was imposed to me for scratching a car while parking three years ago.

I wasn't even aware of it because I changed cities in the meantime, and I probably received these documents in my previous address.

The ticket given to me in the DMV contains virtually zero information on how to proceed in this case. I am currently residing in San Francisco but the ticket is from Los Angeles. Is there any way I can solve the issue locally or should I fly back to talk with the clerk of the address written in the FTA ticket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the situation in L.A., but most courthouses I've dealt with will allow you to just pay the fine online and be done with it.

Try [their website](http://www.lacourt.org/) or call the clerk's office to get more information.